# Finding connected components in Matlab gives wrong results

Tags: matlab, image-processing, multidimensional-array, 3d, cluster-analysis

I have a binary 3D image of size *60*-by-*90*-by-*10*. With the following Matlab code I'm searching for connected voxels of `1`s in the image:

```
conn = 26;
CC = bwconncomp(img, conn);
stats = regionprops(CC,'pixellist');
```

The really weird thing is that stats returns coordinates which are outside of the 3D image.

For example for

```
voxels = stats(6).PixelList;
voxels(23,:)
```

I'm getting a 3D coordinate of `[61,15,4]`.

What is wrong here? Regarding this issue I'm also concerned that the calculation of the connected components is wrong.

Here is the 3D image (as .mat file): https://www.dropbox.com/s/pw3yzbcx4uyhh9s/img.mat?dl=0

Comment: From toe [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html), `PixelList` returns the coordinates in the form `[x y z ...]`. My guess is that it's switching `x` and `y`, because they generally mean `column` and `row`, instead of the default `row` and `column` when acessing a matrix. Anyway, that would be weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .mat-File shows a Matrix with a size of 60x90x10, which means 60 rows, 90 columns and 10 bands, so y=60, x=90 and z=10.

Looks like the calculation is correct, you just got confused about your initial image size... nothing is switched, your image hast just a different size from what you assumed :-) (try `imagesc(img(:,:,1))` to see!)

This row/column vs. x/y thing can be annoying, I know that from experience...

Comment: Why does y stand for rows? In a matrix usually rows are first index and columns second index, so row = x and column = y. With size(M,1) one also gets number of rows...

Comment: Nevertheless, so I'm getting 3D coordinate of (61,15,4) and if I want to look it up in the img I have to take img(15,61,4). Is that right?

Comment: but think again: rows count in the vertical direction, therefore Y (in the 2D case), columns = horizontal = X (at least thats how MATLAB sees it). Display your image and see!

Comment: your Matrix with 60x90x10 means means an image with a width of 90 (=X) and a height of 60 (=Y). Maybe this helps...